# PHP Curl Slowness

Tags: php, performance, curl

For some reason my curl call is very slow. Here is the code I used.

```
$postData = "test"
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Executing this code takes on average 250ms to finish.
However when I just open the url in a browser, firebug says it only takes about 80ms.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is this the overhead associated with PHP Curl.

It's the call to

```
curl_exec
```

That is taking up all the time.

UPDATE:

So I figured out right after I posted this that if I set the curl option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

It significantly slows down

```
curl_exec
```

The post data could be anything and it will slow it down.

Even if I set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

It's slow.

I'll try to work around it by just adding the parameters to the URI as a query string.

SECOND UPDATE:

Confirmed that if I just call the URI using GET and passing parameters
as a query string it is much faster than using POST and putting the parameters in the body.

Comment: is your browser and webserver sharing the same connection?

Comment: Are you located in the same physical location as the server you're running this on?

Comment: are you talking about localhost testing or testing across servers across states or countries.

Answer (score 42):

CURL has some problems with DNS look-ups. Try using IP address instead of domain name.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! This definitely seemed to be the case in my own testing. Swapping the domain name for an IP address reduced the request time from ~10s down to ~0.2s!

Comment: i also, used this solution and reduced the call from 5 seconds to 0.5s! thank you!

Comment: Sometimes you just can't get away from DNS, if using global API's, which are using round-robin or does not even respond if you call them by bare IPv4.

Comment: Some time can not do it, and some site just accessible with domain, and don't open with IP.

Comment: thank you its work. but why? what about when we enforce to use domain?

Answer (score 21):

Curl has the ability to tell exactly how long each piece took and where the slowness is (name lookup, connect, transfer time). Use curl_getinfo (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) after you run curl_exec.

If curl is slow, it is generally not the PHP code, it's almost always network related.

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

Comment: What is "this"? Pleaser add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

Adding "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL);" solved here. Any problem with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this exact problem by ***removing*** the following two options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

Somehow on the site I was fetching, the POST request to over ten full seconds.  If it's GET, it's less than a second.

So... in my wrapper function that does the Curl requests, it now only sets those two options when there is something in `$postData`

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced a massive speed-up through compression. By adding the `Accept-Encoding` header to "gzip, deflate", or just to all formats which Curl supports, my ~200MB download took 6s instead of 20s:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Notes:

- If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.
- you do not even have to care about decompression after the download, as this is done by Curl internally.
- `CURLOPT_ENCODING` [requires Curl 7.10+](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score -1):

The curl functions in php directly use the curl command line tool under *nix systems.

Therefore it really only depends on the network speed since in general curl itself is much faster than a webbrowser since it (by default) does not load any additional data like included pictures, stylesheets etc. of a website.

It might be possible that you are not aware, that the network performance of the server on which you were testing your php script is way worse than on your local computer where you were testing with the browser. Therefore both measurements are not really comparable.

Comment: That's not true. As per docs it uses `libcurl`, it does not use any cli tool 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php

Answer (score -2):

generally thats acceptable when you are loading contents or posting to slower end of world. curl call are directly proportional to your network speed and throughput of your webserver

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable"? A request that takes more than three times is not acceptable after all