# PHP CURL is too slow for localhost

Tags: php, curl

I have setup two apps in my WAMP environment. Performance of both the sites is OK. They return data in less than a second. The problem is that when I curl one site from another the curl takes around 20 seconds to respond. I have done profiling. Actually CURL request is taking all the time.

This should not be the case as both sites are setup on my machine and I am accessing using localhost/127.0.0.1 . Is it some sort of DNS resolve issue?

Comment: Does the _other_ script take 20 seconds to complete?

Comment: is localhost added in system32\drivers\etc\hosts?

Comment: please use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, please check
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304645/php-curl-slowness

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and finally discover that it was coming from two facts :

1. I use Mac OS X Mavericks
2. I accessed my project via the URL `http://myproject.local/` because I put a line `127.0.0.1 myproject.local` in `/etc/hosts`

It is because the `.local` tld is reserved for Bonjour service, and this since Mac OS X Lion (10.7).

Changing the tld for something else fixed the problem.

Comment: Plus one, sorted my problem too. Thanks

Comment: You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is a DNS lookup problem.

On Windows 7 x64 i managed to overcome this issue

(curl call between applications on different ports in localhost) 
by editing the host file
( C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc ).

Un-comment on the line that says:
    127.0.0.1       localhost 
, ***reboot*** and you're done.

Comment: I found that you don't need to reboot for changes to the hosts file to take effect.

Comment: actually for me worked only after rebooting! i tried also without rebooting but it didn't work.

Comment: I see, so at least the first time you edit the hosts file, you should reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting up different virtual hosts such as sitea.dev and siteb.dev If you use the same host for both sites on your localhost Windows machine, then you get a long delay (the same as if there is a Fatal PHP error). It's not a problem with Curl since file_get_contents(url) gave me the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *.local TLD, you can solve this and enjoy fast loading times by adding both, IPv4 and IPv6 entries in the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   test.local
::1         test.local
```

Best

Comment: Why would a comment "changing TLD to something else" be higher than this simple, elegant, fast, answer. Add another line, don't change your TLD, everything is fast again. Thanks Richter